# Autodesk Viewer on Premise

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is it possible to deploy an instance of the Viewer and SVF translation / extractor workflow that does not rely of communicating to external Autodesk APIs, in case of a closed cloud environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has to be on our servers **at least for the duration of the translation to SVF** - there is no way round that.

You can remove both the **original file** and the generated **SVF** from our servers afterwards.